# Как добавить библеотеку с github в xcode проект

Tags: xcode, swift, github, swift3, library

Добрый день, прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую воспользоваться CocoaPods. Вот [тут](https://blog.justdev.org/github/cocoapods-bystryj-start/)  хороший тюториал как это настроить. После этого достаточно просто будет добавлять любую библиотеку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочешь использовать CocoaPods, то просто перетаскивай .xcodeproj скачанного фреймворка в свой проект, в настройках своего проекта в вкладке General добавляй скачанный фреймворк (жми плюс и вводи название скачанного фреймворка) и подписывай в используемых контроллерах import "имя фреймворка"